# Multiple Summer note divs on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the code of a specific summer note div with multiple ones on a single page.

My summer notes are created from a database with php as follows:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <?php $i=-1; foreach($contents as $content): ?>
      <?php $i++; ?>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="<?php echo $content->contentName; ?>">
          <div class="summernote" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
              <?php echo $content->content; ?>
          </div>
      </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

And then my javascript is:

```
<script>
  $('.summernote').summernote({
    onblur: function(e) {
      var id = $('.summernote').data('id');
      var sHTML = $('.summernote').eq(id).code();
      alert(sHTML);
    }
  });
</script>
```

It always gets the first `$('.summernote').eq(0).code();` summernote code never the second or third one.

What I'm trying to do is when each summernote gets a blur, have that code update in a hidden textarea to submit back to the database.

(btw) I am initilizing the summer notes like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
      height: 300,
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: So no solution to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After selecting all summernote's you need to access their attributes by specifying one element like:

```
<script>
  $('.summernote').each(function(i, obj) { $(obj).summernote({
    onblur: function(e) {
      var id = $(obj).data('id');
      var sHTML = $(obj).code();
      alert(sHTML);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: sorry there is another error, I am editing my answer

Comment: According to the summernote api, that is the correct way to do the blur. Copied directly from that site. Your code does not work.

Comment: Sorry I did not know that summercode was a library.

Comment: one last edit to revert .summarnote call and adding e.target instead of this.

Comment: Var id still returns as undefined.

Comment: If you `alert(id);` it returns as `undefined`

Comment: Can you alert (or better console.log) e.target? I am testing this code on summernote's main website, it works..

Comment: It shows this: `<div class="note-editable" contenteditable="true"></div>` so it's not using the div I'm hard coding with the data-id

Comment: I see. Then there does not seem to be a way to access the div using handler function parameter "e". Instead you can traverse divs with jQuery's each like: $('.summernote').each(function(i, obj) { $(obj).summernote({...}) });

Comment: Why not update your answer since that was the question. I won't accept till that happens.

Comment: sure, I was waiting for your confirmation

Comment: @mesutozer can you help me with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664796/repeat-the-summernote-editor-for-all-the-textareas-in-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

To display multiple editors on a page, you need to place more than two `<div>` elements in HTML.

**Example:**

```
<div class="summernote">summernote 1</div>
<div class="summernote">summernote 2</div>
```

**Then run summernote with jQuery selector.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote();
});
```

For more information [click](http://summernote.org/examples/#multiple-editor)

Note: Multiple Editor summernote not work with `id`

Answer (score 0):

I Finally got the code working for multiple summernote editors and image uploading!

To fix

> "undefined"

, try:

> var id = $(obj).data('id');

to

> var id= $(obj).attr('id'))

Source:

https://github.com/neblina-software/balerocms-enterprise/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/js/app.js

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to use summernote to output multiple content with `foreach`, loop/repetitive statement etc

Summernote works for the first output only but you can make it work for others by using the ***class twice***:

```
<div class"summernote summernote"> </div>
```

Provided your script is like this:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.summernote').summernote();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean one can assign several textareas or divs to the same instance of sommernote without instanciating it again for every ta/div one would like to use it on?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using summernote inside a textarea in a form and you intend to apply it on multiple textarea(s) on the same form, replace `id=summernote` with `class="summernote"`

Dont forget to do the same on your initialisation script

```
<script>
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200 //just specifies the height of the summernote textarea
    });
</script>
```

Example

```
<textarea class="summernote" name="valueToBeExtractedBackend" required></textarea>

<script>
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200
    });
</script>
```