# repeat the summernote editor for all the textareas in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, textarea, summernote

I have a cshtml viewpage like below

```
    <div class="form-group">

            @foreach (var fields in Model.ListProductFields)
            {

               @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProductFieldNameEn, fields.FieldName, htmlAttributes: new { id="", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

               <div class="col-md-10">

                  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FieldValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @row = 5 } })

               </div>                    
            }

    </div>
```

using above div section I can populate multiple textareas with its relavant label

this is how it shows when this is working

[image]

Then I try to add summernote rich text editor for all of these text areas ,
using following home-index.js file

```
(function ($) {
    function HomeIndex() {
        var $this = this;

        function initialize() {
            $('#FieldValue').summernote({
                focus: true,
                height: 150,
                codemirror: {
                    theme: 'united'
                }
            });
        }

        $this.init = function () {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        var self = new HomeIndex();
        self.init();
    })
}(jQuery))
```

then its apply for first text area. not apply for rest of the text areas

like below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creating invalid html because each textarea has the same `id` attribute and `('#FieldValue')` will only ever return the first element with `id="FieldValue"`.

In addition this will not bind to your model when you submit the form. Instead, use a `for` loop to generate the html and give the textarea a class name for use as a jQuery selector (note that property `ListProductField` will need to implement `IList` or alternatively you can use a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, Model.ListProductFields[i].FieldName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ListProductFields[i].FieldValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control summernote", @row = 5 } })
    </div>                    
}
```

and change the selector to

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
```

Side note: It appears your `@Html.LabelFor()` is incorrect. It is creating a label associated with property `ProductFieldNameEn` but you control is for property `FieldName`. I think you have the parameters the wrong wa around and it should be

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.ListProductFields[i].FieldName, Model.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn, ...
```

which will associated the label with the following textarea, and display the value of property `ProductFieldNameEn`

Comment: I've tried your approach but then I'm getting all the labels correctly but without summernote editor content, just with text areas . here my whole code is https://dotnetfiddle.net/quuTve , I've changed as you mentored

Comment: I'm trying to customize [this similar PHP question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619110/multiple-summer-note-divs-on-one-page) answer  for this but bit confusing

Comment: That does not really makes sense unless your have got a typo. But then `var self = new HomeIndex(); self.init();` does not make a lot of sense either. Just comment out all the scripts and replace with `$('.summernote').summernote();` to test.

Comment: do I need to apply `$('.summernote').summernote();` code inside `home-index.js` or cshtml page     `<script type="text/javascript"> .. </script>` ?

Comment: Just put it in the `cshtml` page to test that it works

Comment: added in cshtml page like this `@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval","~/bundle/summernote")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.summernote').summernote();
    </script>
}` but not working :(

Comment: Does not make sense. I will have a look at the plugin a bit later and see if it has any special requirements for initialization.

Comment: As I feel I need to loop that in script also , to get the selector , [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619110/multiple-summer-note-divs-on-one-page) its explain how to do with php but I dont know how can I customize to C#

Comment: Give me 10 minutes and I'll create a fiddle

Comment: Works fine for me - refer [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjqzr885/2/) are you sure you have included all the relevant scripts

Comment: yeah that working once I use https://dotnetfiddle.net/quuTve like this, I dont know why this looped solution getting wrong :(

Comment: I think I have mentioned this to your before - there is **NO** point creating DotNetFiddle's that can never be run or tested (you cant use layouts, the method must be named Index, you cannot use bundles etc etc.

Comment: I dont have another way to show my whole code, thats why I used that extremely sorry if its bad approach using as resource , by the way I'm getting [view like this](http://s16.postimg.org/c6ychypb9/view.jpg) once I used those code , As I feel , I hope in my approach I'm looping this results that's why I'm not getting this , am I correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your saying. Is it now working or not? If not then there is something else wrong with your code because the code I showed create the html in the fiddle I linked to. Can you post the actual html which is generated for one of the `<textarea>` elements - it should be `<textarea name="ListProductFields[0].FieldValue" id="ListProductFields_0__FieldValue" class="form-control summernote">....</textarea>`

Comment: Also there is no point adding `new { row="5" }` (the actual `textarea` is hidden) and there is no real point using `@LabelFor()`, again because the `textarea` is hidden (it wont act as a `label`) so you could just as easily use a `<span>@Model.ListProductFields[i].ProductFieldNameEn<span>`

Comment: No its not working , as I feel I hope this is because in my question I'm looping these textareas in server side , but dotnet fiddle [you showed](https://jsfiddle.net/zjqzr885/2/) and [I created](https://dotnetfiddle.net/quuTve) one there is no looping

Comment: The loop has got nothing to do with it - the fiddle just mimics the html generated by the loop. I will create a DotNetFiddle for you a bit later to prove it.

Comment: now this is working I've missed some , resource files in Layout file

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="form-group">

                @foreach (var fields in Model.ListProductFields)
                {

                   @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ProductFieldNameEn, fields.FieldName, htmlAttributes: new { id="", @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

                   <div class="col-md-10">

                      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FieldValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control  mySummerNote", @row = 5 } })

                   </div>                    
                }
    </div>


(function ($) {
    function HomeIndex() {
        var $this = this;

        function initialize() {
            $('.mySummerNote').summernote({
                focus: true,
                height: 150,
                codemirror: {
                    theme: 'united'
                }
            });
        }

        $this.init = function () {
            initialize();
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        var self = new HomeIndex();
        self.init();
    })
}(jQuery))
```

Comment: then first summernote editor for first text area also disappearing :(

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the class in the html and javascript. If the textarea dissappears that may be due to some other error